# Evaluate $\int^1_0 \log^2(1-x) \log^2(x) \, dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, logarithms, improper-integrals, gamma-function

I have no idea where to even start. WolframAlpha cant compute it either.

$$\int^1_0 \log^2(1-x) \log^2(x) \, dx$$

I think it can be done with series, but I am not sure, can someone help a little so I can get a start??

Thanks!

Comment: i only know the result $-8 \zeta (3)+24-\frac{4 \pi ^2}{3}-\frac{\pi ^4}{90}$

Comment: Differentiate the integral representation of the beta function twice w.r.t. $p$ and twice w.r.t. $q$, and then set $p=q=0$. This results into polygamma values which are known to be related to zeta values. The final result simplifies to what is written in the previous comment.

Comment: @O.L., I may need you to be more explicit. What do you mean by "w.r.t p" which variable is $p$ and which variable is $q$ I know the beta function integral, but I am not sure which variables represent what. Can you let me know?

Comment: Another tactic is repeated integration by parts.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the series of $\ln^2(1-x)$,
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\ln^2{x}\ln^2(1-x) \ {\rm d}x
&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{2H_n}{n+1}\int^1_0x^{n+1}\ln^2{x}\ {\rm d}x\\
&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{4H_n}{(n+1)(n+2)^3}
\end{align}
Then integrate $f(z)=\dfrac{(\gamma+\psi_0(-z))^2}{(z+1)(z+2)^3}$ along an infinitely large square. The integral vanishes which implies the sum of its residues is zero. At the positive integers,
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\rm Res}(f,n)
&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=n}\left[\frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)^3(z-n)^2}+\frac{2H_n}{(z+1)(z+2)^3(z-n)}\right]\\
&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{2H_n}{(n+1)(n+2)^3}-\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{4n+5}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^4}\\
&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{2H_n}{(n+1)(n+2)^3}+\frac{\pi^4}{30}+2\zeta(3)-\frac{91}{16}
\end{align}
At $z=0$,
\begin{align}
{\rm Res}(f,0)
&=\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0}\frac{1}{z^2(z+1)(z+2)^3}\\
&=-\frac{5}{16}
\end{align}
At $z=-1$,
\begin{align}
{\rm Res}(f,-1)
&=0
\end{align}
At $z=-2$,
\begin{align}
{\rm Res}(f,-2)
&=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to-2}\frac{{\rm d}^2}{{\rm d}z^2}\frac{(\gamma+\psi_0(-z))^2}{z+1}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^4}{36}+2\zeta(3)+\frac{2\pi^2}{3}-6
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\int^1_0\ln^2{x}\ln^2(1-x)\ {\rm d}x
&=2\left[-\frac{\pi^4}{30}-2\zeta(3)+\frac{91}{16}+\frac{5}{16}+\frac{\pi^4}{36}-2\zeta(3)-\frac{2\pi^2}{3}+6\right]\\
&=-\frac{\pi^4}{90}-8\zeta(3)-\frac{4\pi^2}{3}+24
\end{align}

Comment: where can I learn about this method? I have never learned this, can you tell me a starting point?

Comment: @Amad27 You may want to learn some complex analysis and familarise yourself with the residue theorem first. After which, you may refer to this paper: http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSa98.pdf.

Comment: I read that page. It does not show anything about how you integrated along the square? Please tell me; how do you integrate along a square. And what do you mean the integral "vanishes," making the residue 0?

Comment: please? I just need something to start with.

Comment: @Amad27 I am integrating $f(z)$ over a square contour with vertices $\pm(N+\frac{1}{2})\pm i(N+\frac{1}{2})$ such that we avoid the poles at the integers on the real axis. To check that the contour integral $\to 0$ as $N\to\infty$, we parameterise and note that $\psi_0(z)\sim\ln{z}$ for large $z$. One can then apply the [ML-inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma).  But by the residue theorem, $\displaystyle\oint_{C_N}f(z)\ {\rm d}z=0=2\pi i\sum\text{(residues in contour)}$. The paper above explains how one can determine $f(z)$ such that the unknown sum can be computed.

Comment: why did you specifically have the 1/2 for the vertex? Why not some other number? Thanks for helping I am extremely grateful that you have taken your time to help me! Thank you :)

Comment: the poles are when the denominator =0 if I am correct? Then here: $\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}{\rm Res}(f,n)
&=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=n}\left[\frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)^3(z-n)^2}+\frac{2H_n}{(z+1)(z+2)^3(z-n)}\right]\\ \end{align}$

Can you explain how you got that result?

Comment: @Amad27 Have you read the paper I linked above? I am sure it explains your doubts perfectly upon careful reading. Note that a working knowledge of complex analysis and Laurent series is required for one to grasp this method. Thanks.

Comment: can you atleast tell me which section of the paper. I reread it. It briefly talks about the $\psi(z) + \gamma$ as a series representation, but I cant find where it adresses residues as **infinite sums.** Does this question seem fair for an answer please? I am **really interested** in this solution, but I do need help.... Hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: @Amad27 When dealing with sums of the form $\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}H_n r(n)$, where $r(n)$ is a rational function of $n$, we would most of the time sum up the residues of $(\gamma+\psi_0(z))^2r(z)$. To determine the residues, just expand the digamma function as a Laurent series about the positive integers.

Comment: Firstly I appreciate you answering my questions, some of them are really bad which is why people ignore them most of the time. I assumed that you meant sum up residues of $(\gamma + \psi(-z))^2$ instead of $\psi(z)$. I understand what a Laurent Series is, I studied it a while ago. But I am confused how to find it for a special function like digamma. I looked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469374/the-laurent-series-of-the-digamma-function-at-the-negative-integers  It is for positive integers. What to do here? **I am sorry** for troubling you. But I am very curious..

Comment: can you join me for chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19823/chat-m-n-c-e-and-amad27

Comment: I see you wish not to continue this. I asked a seperate question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084724/calculating-harmonic-sums-with-residues   I see you commented there. Maybe you can answer there if you wish. It would really help, and as you see from the questions Ive asked, I really am desperate to learn this.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with the Beta function
\begin{align}
B(x, y) = \int_{0}^{1} t^{x-1} (1-t)^{y-1} \, dt
\end{align}
differentiate with respect to $x$ and $y$ twice. This leads to
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{1} t^{x-1} (1-t)^{y-1} \, \ln^{2}(t) \, \ln^{2}(1-t) \, dt \\
&= \partial_{x}^{2} \partial_{y}^{2}  B(x,y).
\end{align} 
Now the integral in question is the case for $x=y=1$. For this, it is seen that
\begin{align}
\partial_{x}^{2} \left. B(x,y) \right|_{x=1} = \frac{1}{y} \left[ \psi'(1) - \psi'(y+1) + \left( \psi(1) - \psi(y+1) \right)^{2} \right].
\end{align}
Differential with respect to $y$ yields
\begin{align}
\partial_{y}^{2} \partial_{x}^{2} \left. B(x,y) \right|_{x=1} &= \frac{1}{y} \left[ - \psi'''(y+1) - 2 \psi''(y+1) \left( \psi(1) - \psi(y+1) \right) + 2 \left( \psi'(y+1) \right)^{2} \right] \\
& \hspace{5mm} - \frac{2}{y^{2}} \left[ - \psi''(y+1) - 2 \psi'(y+1) \left( \psi(1) - \psi(y+1) \right) \right] \\
& \hspace{10mm} + \frac{2}{y^{3}} \left[ \psi'(1) - \psi'(y+1) + \left( \psi(1) - \psi(y+1) \right)^{2} \right].
\end{align}
Now
\begin{align}
\partial_{y}^{2} \partial_{x}^{2} \left. B(x,y) \right|_{x=y=1} &= 4 - \psi'''(2) + 4 \psi''(2) - 4 \psi'(2) + 2 \left( \psi'(2) \right)^{2} .
\end{align}
Since 
\begin{align}
\psi'(2) &= \frac{\pi^{2}}{6} -1  \\
\psi''(2) &= 2 - 2\zeta(3) \\
\psi'''(2) &= \frac{\pi^{4}}{45} - 6
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
\partial_{y}^{2} \partial_{x}^{2} \left. B(x,y) \right|_{x=y=1} = 24 - \frac{4 \pi^{2}}{3} - \frac{\pi^{4}}{90} - 8 \zeta(3).
\end{align}

Answer (score 6):

First, letting $x=e^{-t}$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1x^k\log(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty e^{-(k+1)t}\,t^2\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac2{(k+1)^3}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Also, squaring the power series yields
$$
\log(1-x)^2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2H_{k-1}}{k}x^k\tag{2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\log(1-x)^2\log(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2H_{k-1}}{k}x^k\log(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3a}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{4H_{k-1}}{k(k+1)^3}\tag{3b}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\frac4{jk(k+1)^3}\tag{3c}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^k\frac4{jk(k+1)^3}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac4{k^2(k+1)^3}\tag{3d}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac4j\sum_{k=j}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}-\frac1{(k+1)^2}-\frac1{(k+1)^3}\right)\tag{3e}\\
&-4\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(-\frac3k+\frac3{k+1}+\frac1{k^2}+\frac2{(k+1)^2}+\frac1{(k+1)^3}\right)\tag{3f}\\
&=4\zeta(2)-\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac4j\left[\sum_{k=j}^\infty\left(\frac1{k^2}+\frac1{k^3}\right)-\frac1{j^2}-\frac1{j^3}\right]\tag{3g}\\[6pt]
&-4(-6+3\zeta(2)+\zeta(3))\tag{3h}\\[15pt]
&=24-8\zeta(2)-4\zeta(3)\tag{3i}\\[4pt]
&-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^k\frac4j\left(\frac1{k^2}+\frac1{k^3}\right)+4\zeta(3)+4\zeta(4)\tag{3j}\\[2pt]
&=24-8\zeta(2)+4\zeta(4)\tag{3k}\\[6pt]
&-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{4H_k}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{4H_k}{k^3}\tag{3l}\\
&=24-8\zeta(2)-6\zeta(4)-8\zeta(3)+2\zeta(2)^2\tag{3m}\\[6pt]
&=24-\frac{4\pi^2}3-\frac{\pi^4}{90}-8\zeta(3)\tag{3n}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: apply $(2)$
$\text{(3b)}$: apply $(1)$
$\text{(3c)}$: expand $H_{k-1}$
$\text{(3d)}$: add and subtract the $j=k$ term
$\text{(3e)}$: partial fractions: $\frac1{k(k+1)^3}=\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}-\frac1{(k+1)^2}-\frac1{(k+1)^3}$
$\text{(3f)}$: partial fractions: $\frac1{k^2(k+1)^3}=-\frac3k+\frac3{k+1}+\frac1{k^2}+\frac2{(k+1)^2}+\frac1{(k+1)^3}$
$\text{(3g)}$: apply $\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\frac4j\sum\limits_{k=j}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+1}\right)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\frac4{j^2}=4\zeta(2)$ and
$\hphantom{\text{(3g):}}$ $\sum\limits_{k=j}^\infty\left(\frac1{(k+1)^2}+\frac1{(k+1)^3}\right)=\sum\limits_{k=j}^\infty\left(\frac1{k^2}+\frac1{k^3}\right)-\frac1{j^2}-\frac1{j^3}$ to $\text{(3e)}$
$\text{(3h)}$: evaluate $\text{(3f)}$
$\text{(3i)}$: collect the evaluated terms in $\text{(3g)}$ and $\text{(3h)}$
$\text{(3j)}$: change order of summation in $\text{(3g)}$ and evaluate sums
$\text{(3k)}$: collect the evaluated terms in $\text{(3i)}$ and $\text{(3j)}$
$\text{(3l)}$: collect $H_k$ in $\text{(3j)}$
$\text{(3m)}$: use [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/469785) to evaluate the sums in $\text{(3l)}$
$\text{(3n)}$: use $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}6$ and $\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$

Answer (score 5):

**(Too long for comment)**

For what it's worth, I'd like to expand on my comment above about attacking this integral via integration by parts. My main reason for wanting to solve the problem this way is not because it is the easiest way and certainly not because it is the quickest way, but rather because it seems to be the most *elementary* way, relying for the most part on methods accessible to high school students. (My apologies to the OP for just now getting around to writing this, but partially due to the length of the derivation I simply didn't have the time until now.)

We may reduce the evaluation of the definite integral $\mathcal{I}:=\int_{0}^{1}\ln^2{(x)}\ln^2{(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$ to the problem of evaluating a sum of relatively less difficult integrals via integration by parts (IBPs). We'll use $u$ and $u^\prime$ to denote the following functions:

$$\begin{cases}
u{(x)}:=\ln^2{(x)}\ln{(1-x)},\\
v^{\prime}{(x)}:=\ln{(1-x)}.\\
\end{cases}$$

The derivative of $\ln^2{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}$ is:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\ln^2{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}\right)=\frac{2\ln{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}}{x}-\frac{\ln^2{(x)}}{1-x};$$

the indefinite integral of $\ln{(1-x)}$ is:

$$\begin{align}
\int\ln{(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=x\ln{(1-x)}-\int\frac{x}{x-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=x\ln{(1-x)}-x-\ln{(1-x)}+\color{grey}{constant}.
\end{align}$$

Then, choosing $v{(x)}$ by selecting a null constant term in the last line above, we have:

$$\begin{cases}
u^{\prime}{(x)}=\frac{2\ln{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}}{x}-\frac{\ln^2{(x)}}{1-x},\\
v{(x)}=x\ln{(1-x)}-x-\ln{(1-x)}.\\
\end{cases}$$

IBPs in this way yields:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\ln^2{(x)}\ln^2{(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}u{(x)}\,v^{\prime}{(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\left[u{(x)}\,v{(x)}\right]_{0}^{1}-\int_{0}^{1}u^{\prime}{(x)}\,v{(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\left[\ln^2{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}\left(x\ln{(1-x)}-x-\ln{(1-x)}\right)\right]_{0}^{1}\\
&~~~~~ -\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{2\ln{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}}{x}-\frac{\ln^2{(x)}}{1-x}\right)\left(x\ln{(1-x)}-x-\ln{(1-x)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x.\\
\end{align}$$

Note that after integrating by parts both boundary terms vanish identically on the interval $[0,1]$. Thus,

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\left[\ln^2{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}\left(x\ln{(1-x)}-x-\ln{(1-x)}\right)\right]_{0}^{1}\\
&~~~~~ -\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{2\ln{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}}{x}-\frac{\ln^2{(x)}}{1-x}\right)\left(x\ln{(1-x)}-x-\ln{(1-x)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=0-0+\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\ln^2{(x)}}{1-x}-\frac{2\ln{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}}{x}\right)\left(x\ln{(1-x)}-x-\ln{(1-x)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\ln^2{(x)}}{1-x}-\frac{2\ln{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}}{x}\right)\left(x\ln{(1-x)}-x-\ln{(1-x)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\color{green}{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln^2{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x}-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln^2{(x)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x\color{green}{-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\
&~~~~~ \color{brown}{-\int_{0}^{1}2\ln{(x)}\ln^2{(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x}+\int_{0}^{1}2\ln{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\color{brown}{+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2\ln{(x)}\ln^2{(1-x)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\
&=\color{green}{-\int_{0}^{1}\ln^2{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x}\color{orange}{-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\ln^2{(x)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x}+2\int_{0}^{1}\ln{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~ \color{brown}{+2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x)\ln{(x)}\ln^2{(1-x)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{1}\ln{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\color{orange}{+\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2{(x)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x}-\int_{0}^{1}\ln^2{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~ +2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x)\ln{(x)}\ln^2{(1-x)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=1+2\int_{0}^{1}\ln{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2{(x)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}\ln^2{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&~~~~~ +2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x)\ln{(x)}\ln^2{(1-x)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=:1+2\,\mathcal{I}_{1}-\mathcal{I}_{2}-\mathcal{I}_{3}+2\,\mathcal{I}_{4},
\end{align}$$

where in the last line we've simply introduced the constant names $\mathcal{I}_{k},k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$, for convenience to denote the following integrals, respectively:

$$\begin{cases}
\int_{0}^{1}\ln{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x,\\
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2{(x)}}{1-x}\,\mathrm{d}x,\\
\int_{0}^{1}\ln^2{(x)}\ln{(1-x)}\,\mathrm{d}x,\\
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(1-x)\ln{(x)}\ln^2{(1-x)}}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x.\\
\end{cases}$$

Now, the OP noted in the question statement that WolframAlpha was unable to find a closed form for the definite integral $\mathcal{I}$. As one might expect, WA is also unable to find an anti-derivative for the corresponding indefinite integral. HOWEVER, it turns out that WolframAlpha *does* return anti-derivatives for each of the four integrals $\mathcal{I}_{k},k\in\{1,2,3,4\}$. WA is also capable of returning closed form values for each of the definite integrals except $\mathcal{I}_{4}$, which has the longest and most complicated anti-derivative of the bunch.

Comment: this is a good answer. Just a question. Do you know about the M.N.C.E. method? How I can use that? It looks interesting

Comment: @Amad27 I am aware of the method, but I don't understand it that well. It's based on residue theory, which is a standard component of any complex analysis course.

Comment: Do you where I can get a start or a textbook (that perhaps you read,**introductory only**) that I can start learning that. The method of Residues is of great interest to me! If you understand it even some bit, will you help me learn it?

Comment: @Amad27 I believe the standard introductory text is [Saff & Snider](http://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Analysis-Applications-Engineering-Mathematics/dp/0139078746). Beyond that, I'm really not the best person to ask.