# What does it mean for an integral to "vanish"?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, analysis

I had a question;

What does it mean for an integral to vanish in complex analysis?

There is supposedly something, which says if the integral "vanishes," the sum of the residues is 0.

But what does it mean for the integral to "vanish," does it mean to diverge? To equal $0$?

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vanish

*Vanish* Mathematics. (of a number, quantity, or function) to become zero.

Comment: can you advise me then: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959701/evaluate-int1-0-log21-x-log2x-dx/960157?noredirect=1#comment2074528_960157 please take a look at M.N.C.E's method. It says the integral $f(z)$ vanishes. But how can I check it evaluates to $0$? M.N.C.E. doesnt state the lower and upper limit, how can I check? From $-\infty \to +\infty$ the integral DIVERGES. Help?

Comment: @Amad27 You should ask MNCE.

Comment: I did. but I didnt get a reply back.