# Explanation for summation complex analysis method

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

*This is @Amad27 something happened to my account, which I will get fixed soon, so for now I will ask as a guest until the problem is fixed.* Thanks.

I saw this method of calculating:

$$I = \int_{0}^{1} \log^2(1-x)\log^2(x) dx$$

[Evaluate $\int^1_0 \log^2(1-x) \log^2(x) \, dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/959701/evaluate-int1-0-log21-x-log2x-dx)

Can you take a look at M.N.C.E.'s method?

I dont understand a few things.

Somehow he makes the relation:

$$\frac{4H_n}{(n+1)(n+2)^3} = \frac{\left(  \gamma + \psi(-z)   \right)^2}{(z+1)(z+2)^3}$$

How is this established?

And this I dont understand, why did he integrate it,?

And then after he states: "At the positive integers," what is he doing with the residues. I know the residue theorem etc, but I dont understand what he is exactly doing?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is *not* the case that
$$
\frac{4H_n}{(n+1)(n+2)^3}=\frac{(\gamma+\psi(-z))^2}{(z+1)(z+2)^3}
$$
What is being used are the residues of $f(z)=\frac{(\gamma+\psi(-z))^2}{(z+1)(z+2)^3}$.

Using the relation
$$
\gamma+\psi(-z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{k+1}+\frac1{z-k}\right)
$$
we get that the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=n\in\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\ge0$ is
$$
\frac{2H_n}{(n+1)(n+2)^3}-\frac{4n+5}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^4}
$$
Furthermore, we get that the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=-1$ is $0$ and at $z=-2$ is
$$
2\zeta(3)-2-\left(2-\frac{\pi^2}6\right)^2
$$
On a path that stays away from the negative integers (say more than $\frac13$ away), $|f(z)|\sim\frac{\log(|z|)^2}{|z|^4}$. Therefore, we get
$$
\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_R}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=0
$$
where $\gamma_R=Re^{2\pi i[0,1]}$. This means that the sum of the residues must be $0$. Therefore,
$$
0=2\zeta(3)-2-\left(2-\frac{\pi^2}6\right)^2+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{2H_n}{(n+1)(n+2)^3}-\frac{4n+5}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^4}\right)
$$
From there, he solves for $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2H_n}{(n+1)(n+2)^3}$.

---

**The Residue of $\boldsymbol{f(z)}$ at $\boldsymbol{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ where $\boldsymbol{n\ge0}$**

Consider $(\gamma+\psi(z))^2$:
$$
\small\left(1+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1z}+\frac12+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1{z-1}}+\frac13+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1{z-2}}+\dots\right)\left(1+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1z}+\frac12+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1{z-1}}+\frac13+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1{z-2}}+\dots\right)
$$
At $z=n$, the coefficient of $\frac1{(z-n)^2}$ is $1$.

At $z=n$, the coefficient of $\frac1{z-n}$ is
$$
\small2\left(1+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1n}+\frac12+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1{n-1}}+\dots+\frac1n+\color{#0000FF}{1}+\frac1{n+1}+\color{#C00000}{0}+\frac1{n+2}-\color{#0000FF}{1}+\frac1{n+3}-\color{#0000FF}{\frac12}+\dots\right)
$$
The factor of $2$ in front is because there is one $\frac1{z-n}$ in the left factor and one in the right. The red $0$ is a placeholder for the $\frac1{z-n}$ that was accounted for in the coefficient for $\frac1{(z-n)^2}$.

The blue $-1-\frac12-\dots$ cancels the black $1+\frac12+\dots$

The remainder is the blue $\frac1n+\frac1{n-1}+\frac1{n-2}+\dots+1=H_n$.

Thus, the coefficient of $\frac1{z-n}$ is $2H_n$.

The coefficient of $\frac1{z-n}$ in $f(z)$ is
$$
\color{#0000FF}{2H_n}\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)^3}+\color{#0000FF}{1}\left[\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\frac1{(z+1)(z+2)^3}\right]_{z=n}
$$
which is
$$
\frac{2H_n}{(n+1)(n+2)^3}-\frac{4n+5}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^4}
$$

Comment: This is a phenomenal answer. Do you mind if I ask a few questions?

Also, how did you get this residues idea? :

"Residue of $f(z)$ at $z=n\in\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\ge0$ is
$$
\frac{2H_n}{(n+1)(n+2)^3}-\frac{4n+5}{(n+1)^2(n+2)^4}
$$"  How did you get this? I tried really hard, but I cant get the residues in form of a sum involving harmonic numbers.

Also, I have always been interested.

$|f(z)|\sim\frac{\log(|z|)^2}{|z|^3}$

How can you say those are similar?

Comment: @Amad27: I have added a section on the computation of the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=n\in\mathbb{Z}$ for $n\ge0$.

Comment: @Amad27: As long as we choose a path that stays more than $\frac13$ away from a negative integer, $\psi(z)\sim\log(z)$ for large $z$, we get that $\left|\,\frac{(\gamma+\psi(-z))^2}{(z+1)(z+2)^3}\,\right| \sim\frac{\log(|z|)^2}{|z|^4}$.

Comment: this is even better. Care for another question? How did you get that series representation for $f(z)$? If you can tell me that, I think I almost got this. =)

Comment: @Amad27: I don't give a series representation for $f(z)$. What is it you are asking for?

Comment: Its not showing properly, it is the line below: consider $(\gamma + \psi(z))^2$

Comment: That is just from the line which says $$\gamma+\psi(-z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{k+1}+\frac1{z-k}\right)$$ This is a common formula for $\psi(z)$ that can be found on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula).

Comment: right, sorry, next. How is the coefficient of $1/(z-n)^2$ at $z=n$ $=1$? $1/(z-n)^2$ doesnt exist at $z=n$?

Comment: @Amad27: There is one $\frac1{z-n}$ in the left factor and one $\frac1{z-n}$ in the right factor. Thus, in the product of the left and the right, we have $\frac1{(z-n)^2}$.

Comment: Thanks. I understood that, but when you let $z=n$ it becomes undefined. So the coefficent cant be $1$ because the whole thing is undefined. Wait, Are you talking about a different $z$ like $z_1$ such that $z \ne n$?

Comment: @Amad27: yes. When talking about the residues and poles of a complex function at $z=\alpha$, we need to talk about $z$ in a neighborhood of $\alpha$.

Comment: And following: "at $z=n$ the coefficient of $1/(z-n)$ is..." How did you get the following line? I cant seem to understand, how you get the **coefficients**?

Comment: Can we please chat? I am really **really** interested in this method, and you are helping me greatly, will you please chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19888/discussion-between-amad27-and-robjohn).

Comment: What "coefficients," are you talking about? What are coefficients in this case? And why are you find them at $z=n$? Please, I am really requesting for your help. Not even a lot at once, just slight help. **Pretty please...!!**

Comment: We are talking about the coefficients of the [Laurent Expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series) about the point $z=n$.

Comment: Where $n > 0$ or $n < 0$ also, how did you derive this coefficient? Wikipedia described a complicated line integral?

Comment: @Amad27: I've described, in detail, how to compute the coefficients for $n\ge0$. The singularities at $z=-1$ and $z=-2$ are simpler.

Comment: Im sorry for being a bother, but I am not sure how to? I reread carefully, but I dont know **how** but I see what....

Comment: @Amad27: You are not sure how to *do what*? Do you see how to compute the Laurent Expansion of $f(z)$ about $z=n$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n\ge0$?

Comment: That is the issue, I am not sure for a general $n$. Will you perhaps show it for a simpler example? Thanks =)

Comment: Perhaps you can give me a link to where i can learn this? On wikipedia, the coefficient is a contour integral. I am not sure what method you are using.

Comment: Consider the case $n=1$. Look at the line following "Consider $(\gamma+\psi(z))^2$:" $$
\begin{align} &\left[\frac1{z-1}+\left(1+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1z}+\frac12 +\color{#C00000}{0} +\frac13+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1{z-2}}+\dots\right)\right]^2\\
&=\frac1{(z-1)^2}+\frac2{z-1}\left(1+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1z}+\frac12 +\color{#C00000}{0} +\frac13+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1{z-2}}+\dots\right)\\
&+\left(1+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1z}+\frac12+\color{#C00000}{0} +\frac13+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1{z-2}}+\dots\right)^2\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
&=\frac1{(z-1)^2}+\frac2{z-1}\left(1+\color{#0000FF}{\frac11}+\frac12 +\color{#C00000}{0} +\frac13+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1{-1}}+\dots+O(z-1)\right)\\
&+\left(1+\color{#0000FF}{\frac11}+\frac12 +\color{#C00000}{0} +\frac13+\color{#0000FF}{\frac1{-1}}+\dots+O(z-1)\right)^2\\
&=\frac1{(z-1)^2}+\frac{2\cdot\color{#0000FF}{\frac11}}{z-1}+O(1)\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I know $O$ means the continued pattern. But what would be $O(1)$ mean? I see what you did here, very nice. I see how you do it for one number. Now in a while I will try for the general $n$, until then can you please answer the above question? Thanks =)

Comment: @Amad27: No, $O$ is the [Landau big-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). $O(1)$ represents a bounded function.

Comment: What allows you to not let $z=1$ in $\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}$?? I tried for a general $n$: In the next comment

Comment: $$\frac{1}{(z-1)^2} + \frac{2}{z-1} \cdot \left( 1 + 1/n + 1/2 + 0 + 1/3 + 1/(n-2)     \right)  $$ Its not going correct as you can see...

Comment: @Amad27: why, for a general $n$, are you looking at powers of $z-1$? You want to expand in powers of $z-n$, not $z-1$.

Comment: I am understanding this more. Why was it required to find the coefficient of $\frac{1}{(z-n)^2}$ ?? Also did you expand $(\psi(-z) + \gamma)^2)$ series form? and then find the coefficient?

Comment: I get the Harmonic sum part of the resiue at $z=n$ but I dont understand why $$\frac{d}{dz} \frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)^3}$$ is also part of the residue. Care to help? Thanks!

Comment: @Amad27: Because of the $\frac1{(z-n)^2}$ from $(\gamma+\psi(z))^2$. We need the coefficient of the $(z-n)$ term from $\frac1{(z+1)(z+2)^3}$.

Comment: Thanks for helping, okay so let see here. I am not sure. Why are we finding the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z-n}$ from the $\frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)^3}$ term?

Comment: @Amad27: I did not say we want the coefficient of the $\frac1{z-n}$ term from $\frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)^3}$; that is $0$ anyway. Because $(\gamma+\psi(z))^2$ has a singularity at $z=n$ whose highest order term is $\frac1{(z-n)^2}$ we need to know the coefficient of the $(z-n)$ term from $\frac{1}{(z+1)(z+2)^3}$ so that in the product of the two, we know the coefficient of the $\frac1{z-n}$ term.

Comment: Is it also true that on any path that stays away from the negative integers, $\psi^{(m)} (z) \sim \frac{(-1)^{m-1}(m-1)!}{z^{m}}$ for large $z$?

Comment: As long as the path stays away from the negative real axis, say $\mathrm{Re}(z)\ge\lambda|z|$ for some $\lambda\gt-1$, and $|z|$ stays large.

Comment: But then isn't $\psi(z) \sim \ln z$ for large $z$ also only true if the path stays away from the negative real axis?  In your answer you seem to say that the path only needs to stay away from the negative integers, not the entire negative real axis.

Comment: Using the identity $\psi\!\left(\frac12+z\right)-\psi\!\left(\frac12-z\right)=\pi\tan(\pi z)$, we have $$ \psi\!\left(-n+\tfrac12+iy\right)=\overbrace{\pi i\tanh(\pi y)}^\text{bounded}+\psi\!\left(n+\tfrac12-iy\right) $$ so the estimate also works if the path crosses the real axis halfway between neighboring negative integers.